# How JS Repository Pattern works

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, repository-pattern

At the moment I'm trying to understand how websites fetch their data.
I picked one website and monitored the network traffic but I couldn't find any request, which contains the information, which are displayed on the website.
After some more investigation, I found three Javascript files, which probably fetch the data. The Javascript files contained the "Repository Pattern".
So, at this moment I'm stuck.

I don't know, how this repositories work in Javascript. Do they fetch their data via API or is the a local database in my browser?
I didn't find any API call in the network traffic from Google Chrome console, which initialized a possible database or fetched data from a server. But I also didn't find a local database (I took a look via Google Chrome console).

My best guess is, that the repositories fetch their data via API and they hide their calls, because the session data from my browser are saved in the repositories, too.

So in conclusion, I want to ask to help me to better understand,

- how Repositories in Javascript work
- how they fetch their data (where is the database, online or offline)
- how can I see the API calls, which are made by these repositories.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Design patterns are just guidelines on how to organise your code, they're rarely contain specific implementation details like whether to gather data from an HTTP end-point or localStorage. If you want to understand how some specific website works, you'll have to dig into its code.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I found nothing useful in these three Javascript files but I will take a look again. Most probably all the important information are stored in the obfuscates Javascript file. But then I don't understand, why I can't see the traffic in the network sniffer from Google Chrome

Comment: Well, the most obvious way to include information in a web site is to include it in the HTML or JavaScript code.

Comment: "I'm trying to understand how websites fetch their data" all the data comes from a server, either in the initial document or xhr/fetch requests. You can store some of it locally in e.g. localStorage, but it always came from a server. "files contained the 'Repository Pattern'" how do you know? Also the "repository pattern"...isn't really a thing? "I didn't find any API call in the network traffic" then it came in during the page load. "fetch their data via API and they hide their calls" you can't do that. There's no "hiding calls".

Comment: "*The Javascript files contained the "Repository Pattern".*" - what? How do you know? To identify a pattern, you'd have to understand the pattern, so if you already did identify it, it's not clear what you are asking for